# Is Python's calendar.month_name implementation of an empty string in the first index good practice or poor design?

Tags: design, python

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) states:

> An array that represents the months of the year in the current locale.
>   This follows normal convention of January being month number 1, so it
>   has a length of 13 and month_name[0] is the empty string.

Is this level of skeuomorphism warranted? Or is it confusing and potentially bug prone to start an array of expected values with no value?

Answer (score 1):

It's better (and less confusing) to have the empty [0] placeholder at the beginning of the array so that you can just plug the month directly into the array indexer, than it is to start January at month 0 and have to perform a bit of conversion math to get the correct array index each time.

Sensible date implementations should not allow a month zero.  Note that, [for historical reasons](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), arrays typically start at an array index of zero.

Comment: Should it be `''` rather than `None`, though? The latter would cause noticeable trouble more quickly if something did end up accessing `month_name[0]`.

Comment: You can put whatever you want there.

Comment: Why not overload the [] function such that month_name[0] throws an error?

Comment: That's probably a good idea.